# Yet another Angular ng-repeat of nested data in a table issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, smart-table

I've been struggling to properly display my data in a table using Angular's ng-repeat. This should be really straightforward, as there are plenty of examples out there. I think the issue has something to do with namespacing, where I use `self.all` as the variable for my data in my js file.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-controller="TransferController as transfers">

    <table st-table="transfers" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in transfers.all">
          <td>Period: {{ row.period }}</td>
          <td colspan="2">Upload Date: {{ row.uploadDate | date }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="code in transfers.all.sections">
          <td colspan="3">Transfer Code: {{ code.transferCode }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

TransferController.js:

```
angular
  .module("RssTransfers")
  .controller("TransferController", ["$http", "$filter", function($http, $filter) {

    var self = this;
    self.all = [];

    function getTransfers() {
      $http
        .get("http://localhost:3000/transfers/api")
        .then(function(response) {
          self.all = response.data.transfers;
      })
    }

    console.log(self);
    getTransfers();
}]);
```

Sample data:

```
[{
"period": 4,
"uploadDate": "2015-11-19T21:00:00.000Z",
"section":[{
  "transferCode": 8675309,
  "details": [
    {
      "voucherNumber": [34, 22],
      "vendor": "jimmy",
      "description": "blah      ",
      "amount": "t        45,555.00"
    }
  ]
}]
},
{
"period": 4,
"uploadDate": "2015-11-19T21:00:00.000Z",
"section":[{
  "transferCode": 45576543,
  "details": [
    {
      "voucherNumber": 22,
      "vendor": "Jonson",
      "description": "trap music      ",
      "amount": "t        12,345.00"
    }
  ]
}]

}]
```

I tried to put together a plunker but couldn't get Angular working for some reason. When I run this, `period` and `uploadDate` render on the page fine, but the row for `transferCode` does not render at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated; I imagine it's a simple mistake on my part.

**EDIT:**
My bad. I put incorrect sample data up initially. I did not include the `section` object. The correct model is up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over `section` of the `all.transfers` array but `all.transfers` does not have any `section` property. Instead, each iterable of `all.transfers` has a section property.

So, in order to iterate over `section` property of each iterable, you have to place the second `ngRepeat` in the first `ngRepeat` like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in transfers.all">
    <td>Period: {{ row.period }}</td>
    <td colspan="2">Upload Date: {{ row.uploadDate | date }}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="code in row.sections">
        {{code.transferCode}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It was an error in the sample data, as the data I'm working with does include the `section` object. I edited my question and the correct data model is up now.

Comment: again you are iterating over 'sections' but the property is 'section'

Comment: Yeah, I tried `section` and `sections` and neither work.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!! It renders, albeit in a pretty ugly fashion. I didn't know I had to nest the second `ng-repeat` within the first, but you saying that makes a ton of sense. Thanks again!